# C# DrawEllipse определение координат

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Отрисовав 2 эллипса

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawEllipse(myPen, 150, 70, 300, 300);
Pen myPen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
Graphics u = e.Graphics;
u.DrawEllipse(myPen1, 165, 85, 270, 270);
```

Хочу узнать по событию MouseClick попал ли пользователем курсором между ними.
Пытался брать значение x и y по нажатию

```
int x = e.X; 
int y = e.Y;
```

Но не понимаю какое условие использовать

Comment: можно попробовать через математику: нужно знать координаты двух фокусов и большую полуось - после этого будет легко определить принадлежность к одному из элипсов

Comment: скажи что означают 4 цифры в методе отрисовки эллипса - возможно я помогу с формулами

Comment: @dgzargo первые 2 значения отступы от верхнего левого края формы, последние 2 размеры ограничивающего прямоугольника
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a3fd63x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "размеры ограничивающего прямоугольника" - большая и малая оси? (тогда у тебя получатся окружности, верно?)

Comment: @dgzargo эллипс вписан в этот прямоугольник то бишь 2a и 2b
Да, окружности получаются)
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: Что значит "между ними"? В точку пересечения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно рисовать не эллипсы, а `GraphicsPath` с отрисовкой эллипса:

```
using (var myPen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
using (var myPen2 = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
{
    DrawPath(e.Graphics, myPen1, rectangle1);
    DrawPath(e.Graphics, myPen2, rectangle2);
}

private void DrawPath(Graphics g, Pen pen, Rectangle rectangle)
{
    using (var path = GetEllipsePath(rectangle))
    {
        g.DrawPath(pen, path);
    }
}

private GraphicsPath GetEllipsePath(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(rectangle);
    return path;
}
```

, где `rectangle1` и `rectangle2` это нужные вам прямоугольники, описывающие эллипс:

```
Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(150, 70, 300, 300);
Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(165, 85, 270, 270);
```

Для определения принадлежности точки экземпляру `GraphicsPath` воспользуемся методом `IsVisible`. Т.о., метод, показывающий, находится ли определенная точка между указанными эллипсами будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private bool IsPointBetweenEllipses(Point p)
{
    using (var path1 = GetEllipsePath(rectangle1))
    using (var path2 = GetEllipsePath(rectangle2))
    {
        return path1.IsVisible(p) ^ path2.IsVisible(p);
    }
}
```

PS. Практически все примитивы из `System.Drawing` реализуют `IDisposable`. Поэтому не забывайте их высвобождать.

Answer (score 0):

вариант принадлежности точки к эллипсу через математическое определение
[image: немного теории]

```
int a = 300;//большая полуось
int b = 300;//малая полуось
int x = 150, y = 70;
int f1f2 = sqrt(a*a-b*b)*2;//расстояние между фокусами
int f1 = x + a/2 - f1f2/2;
int f2 = x + a/2 + f1f2/2;
int fy = y + b/2;

if (diastance(e.X,e.Y,f1,fy) + diastance(e.X,e.Y,f1,fy) <= 2*a)
{
//точка в эллипсе
}
```

метод distance:

```
float diastance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
  int d1 = abs(x1-x2);
  int d2 = abs(y1-y2);
  return sqrt(d1*d1 + d2*d2);
}
```